# How to construct and redirect to a url in perl mason

Tags: perl, redirect, mason

From my .mi file, I want to do a redirect to  a relative url and pass parameters 'x' and 'y'. Redirection should happen to -

> /a/b/c?x=1&y=2

Please suggest how can this be done.

I am trying

```
$m->redirect((url => $Std->url('/gp/prime/pipeline/signup',{ protocol => 'https', get => {'x' => '1', 'y' => '2'}}))
```

But does not work. :(

Answer (score 0):

You could use `$m->redirect()` and `make_uri()`, like this:

```
$m->redirect( make_uri( '/a/b/c', { 'x' => 1, 'y' => 2 }), 302 );
```